# Fetching recent/historical queries run on a database from an application

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm getting some database errors from an application related to unique constraints however none of the records have any duplicate values so I want to check what query was run that produced the error.

How can I check a history log of queries to pinpoint the problem? I'm using Oracle 12c

Comment: This question will be better appreciated at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are the unique constraints which are being violated on a column which contains values obtained from a SEQUENCE, or are these constraints on a column or columns derived from and external data source and/or user input?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Oracle `V$SQL` view:

```
SELECT *
FROM v$sql s
WHERE PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME = 'FOO'
ORDER BY s.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME DESC nulls last;
```

In this example the result is already filtered by `PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME` which is the user name that executed the sql.

See [Oracle Documentation on V$SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn30246.htm#REFRN30246) for details